# Stringify/serialize array with property values to text and reproduce

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, serialization, stringify

Am working with fairly massive arrays for some text-processing/analysing and need a way to store the computed database into a textfile.
The datastructure can look as follows and has to be accessible exactly as seen here (not with loops or something else):

```
var arr = [];
arr["a"] = "A";
arr["b"] = 5;
arr["c"] = "C";

console.log(arr["a"])
console.log(arr["b"])
console.log(arr["c"])
```

Of course I tried the standard method stringify:

```
DATA = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(DATA);
arr = JSON.parse(DATA);
```

However, that doesn't work unfortunately since property values are not stringified and thus DATA is empty.

Now is there a smooth way to achieve this that also works with nested arrays?
The values of the properties are either strings or numbers.

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: Arrays only have numeric indices. You are morphing an array into an array like object which is not a good idea if you want to stringify it. Make it an object to start with

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `var arr = {}`

Comment: There's a note on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) page about cases like this: "*// String-keyed array elements are not enumerable and make no sense in JSON*"